# WPF: Position form elements on Canvas or Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I kind of prefer to drag controls around on a canvas via the visual studio designer, so that each control has an x and y coordinate. I find it alot faster than using a grid. But I still see alot of articles out there that use a grid for laying out controls, so that each control has a row, column. What are your thoughts on this, is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 2):

By using a canvas it's much harder to get everything resized in a good way, other controls will resize automaticly (if not fixed size ofcourse)

Answer (score 1):

It takes some practice to use the various containers, but it is worth it. When your control is located in a container resizing works automatically and your XAML stays more organized.

Check out easy to use third part containers like [autogrid](http://wpfcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AutoGrid&referringTitle=Home).

Answer (score 1):

Standard guidance from MS is to avoid using the Canvas for laying out controls.

Quote from MSDN Canvas documentation:

> Canvas is the only panel element that
>   has no inherent layout
>   characteristics. A Canvas has default
>   Height and Width properties of zero,
>   unless it is the child of an element
>   that automatically sizes its child
>   elements. Child elements of a Canvas
>   are never resized, they are just
>   positioned at their designated
>   coordinates. This provides flexibility
>   for situations in which inherent
>   sizing constraints or alignment are
>   not needed or wanted. For cases in
>   which you want child content to be
>   automatically resized and aligned, it
>   is usually best to use a Grid element.

So, I'd take that to mean that in most situations you would not want to use the Canvas and rather use the Grid (or another panel) to contain your various child UI elements.  I personally find the Grid sufficient for most needs.

References:

Canvas - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx

Globalization and Localization - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To use grid (row & column ) is preferred because it does not depend on screen resolution.

Comment: WPF doesn't use pixel coordinates, but 1/96 inch screen unit coordinates. It scales when screen resolution changes. Larger monitors will however give more room for the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Its wrong cause WPF supports other alternative read directions. If the localization changes, for WPF its impossible to remap X/Y coordinates, but in a Grids and StackPanels the logical arrangement can get inversed / changed.

Its very seldom good to absolutely position the elements

Comment: I don't think it is a selling argument in itself to support Asian or Arabic cultures, if that will never be your target audience, but there are other good reasons not to use a canvas.

Comment: The Point is to support Localization standards in a all-embracing way. And for that its not wise to ignore the read direction. But i totally agree that there are only few cases were it makes a real difference.